# Quartz Scheduling Application

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I am writing a Scheduling Client Server Application. The Server Application uses Window Service using Quartz and the Client application (For testing using both WEB and Console Applications) . Both client /Server Project build successfully but when i start service and my console application communicate with this service .An exception Comes when Client Object Calls : sched.ScheduleJob(Job,Trigger)

it through Exception on this line.

Below is my code snippet

```
namespace QuartzService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
    private IScheduler sched;
    public void Show()
    {
        try {
            NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteServer";

            // set thread pool info
            properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

            // set remoting exporter
            properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.port"] = "555";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = "QuartzScheduler";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName"] = "httpQuartz";
            /// properties =           (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz");
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            sched = sf.GetScheduler();
            sched.Start();
            string lines = "==================Start===========================\n"+DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()+"\n====================END=========================\n";

            // Write the string to a file.
            string filepath = @"D:\Murtaza\Service\test.txt";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt",true);
            file.WriteLine(lines);

            file.Close();
         //   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
           // Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

          //  sched.Shutdown(true);
        }
        catch { }

    }
}
```

}

===============================
Here is Client Console Application Code:

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
            NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteClient";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
            // set thread pool info
            properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

            // set remoting expoter
            properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://10.0.0.46:555/QuartzScheduler";// "tcp://10.0.0.85:555/QuartzScheduler"; //"tcp://10.0.0.46:555/QuartzScheduler";

            // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>()
                .WithIdentity("remotelyAddedJob", "default")
                .Build();

            JobDataMap map = job.JobDataMap;
            map.Put("msg", "Your remotely added job has executed!");

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("remotelyAddedTrigger", "default")
                .ForJob(job.Key)
                .WithCronSchedule("/5 * * ? * *")
                .Build();

                // schedule the job
                sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful empty catch blocks. It is like hiding the trash under the carpet. Tell me, how do you know where is the exception line? DO NOT USE EMPTY TRY/CATCH it is better to remove them altogether

Comment: i know steve about Empty Catch but my question is first client communicate with Server then we check the other. Althoug  the Exception Mession is live 'Could not load file or assembly 'Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.